# in quickblox video chat audio not working

Tags: ionic-framework, quickblox

Microphone not works in quickblox video chat.
In Android 6.0 video chat video works very well, but microphone not works..Also i gave permission for microphone.please tell me the solution for the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you.